# Max RAM for Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

What is the max amount of RAM that Windows 7 64 bit Boot Camp partition in my late 2011 2.4 i5 MBP 8.1 with OS X Lion can utilize?

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp doesn't restrict the amount of RAM available, therefore the maximum is the maximum as delineated by Windows 7 64 bit, [192 GB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7).

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 7 64 Bit OS via BootCamp will utilize the available RAM on your Mac which is 16 GB (max).